# Apache Tomcat how to enable apache juli logs for org.apache.tomcat.jdbc

Tags: tomcat, logging, jdbc

After Googling much I am not able to find a way to enable tomcat logging on specific package org.apache.tomcat.jdbc

I also need to write these logs in separate file. Help required

I tried this so far

```
############################################################
# Logs specific to org.apache.tomcat.jdbc
# Log level is ALL to print all possible logs
############################################################

5localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
5localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
5localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = jdbc.

org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.level = ALL
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.handlers = 5localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

But this is creating an empty log file with prefix jdbc.

Any clue.